# jwt_authentication request ajax - symfony

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, jwt

I'm working with symfont and JSON Web Token and Symfony.

I'm trying to get jwt with ajax, but I get 401 (Unauthorized)
The problem is with ajax, because i try with postman and I can get the token.

here is my security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Users
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_app_manager:
            pattern:  ^/user/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: users
            json_login:
                check_path: /user/login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false


        app_api_manager:
            pattern:  ^/mngr/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: users
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

here is my ajax

```
var data = {
    'email':email,
    'password':password
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/user/login",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: Can you provide your complete security.yml please ?

Comment: @kemicofa i already update the quesion with the complete security.yml

Comment: Try to change in ```access_control```  section in path ```^/user/login``` instead of ^/login

Answer (score 1):

Try post instead of ajax:

```
        $(document).ready(function{
            //form submit
            $("form").submit(function(event){
                var email      = $('#email').val();
                var password   = $('#password').val();
                $.post("/user/login",{
                    email:email, password: password
                }).done(function(data){

                })
            })
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your answe, i try and i still 401 (Unauthorized) and i don't have the jwt because that request is to ask it

Answer (score 1):

In access_control add path

- { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

instead of

- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

and make sure to include this path in **routes.yaml**

```
user_login:
 path: /user/login
 methods: ['POST']
```